# React Native: State updating based on previous value on app refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I was just playing around with few things and observed this behavior; I can't find the reason anywhere. I have an initial array state [1, 2], in useEffect I have been updating the state based on prev values

```
const [myArr, setArray] = useState([1, 2])
useEffect(() => {
   setArray((prevValues) => [...prevValues, ...newData]);
}, [])
```

Every time I reload my app, the state is keep on appending newData to prevValues, How come the state is not updating based on initial array values? How come state knows the previous array even though I refresh the emulator?

```
Instead of this,
newData = [3,4]
myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4]

updating like this,
newData = [3,4]
myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4]
```

Is it wrong to update state values based on prev values in useEffect? Want to understand this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

every time you reload, myArr back to the initial value. if you want keep the pervious value you should keep the myArr in the state manager like redux or save it in your local storage